# Time Zone Adjustments (Central to Eastern)

Tags: sql-server

I am using following WHERE clause in my SELECT statement

```
WHERE O.OrderDate > {fn curdate()} and O.OrderDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

My goal is to retrieve whole day data from starting of the day till the time query runs. But I found that both the machine and sql server belongs to two different times because of which I am not getting right results.

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix my statement to get accurate results?

Server Time Zone is Central and my machine is in Eastern Time Zone

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: UTC might work better for you in this situation.

Comment: can you please elaborate it a bit? sorry its my first time dealing with times

Comment: I have never personally had to deal with a time situation like this. UTC just makes sense in a situation like this since it is universal. Looking into your query a bit more though, the current_timestamp function should be retrieving the timestamp from the server that the SQL instance is running on. Not the PC the query was executed from. Have you validated that you are missing records when you run the query? What version of SQL is the server running?

Comment: Yeah totally makes sense. I thought current_timestamp would be user machine's time. Yes results are cut off of one hour. What do you suggest, is there an alternate to current_timestamp for local machine's time or I should go through conversion process? thank you for your time looking into this

Comment: In your original post you said you just want the entire days worth of results. If that is the case you dont really care what the current time stamp is. Change out your "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" with "CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' 11:59 PM'". Does that work for you?

Comment: @Chris why 11:59 PM? Why are you converting to an ambiguous and problematic format like 101? What if they're in Canada? You know that things can happen after 11:59 PM but before midnight, right? And after 23:59:59.997 too, if using datetime2? Please see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @Aaron I don't understand why people on this site feel the need to tear apart peoples posts. My apologies for not being at your level. I am helping this person in the best way I know how. Instead of taking several jabs at me why not recommend a solution and explain why it is better than what I posted? The information you provided was very good. I will be reading that thoroughly.

Comment: WOW @Chris I haven't checked the possible solution mentioned there but I am really impressed with you man. Loved your attitude :) checking solutions now..

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks a lot for your reply man. I am checking it..

Comment: @Chris I am not "taking jabs" I am merely encouraging you to question your own recommendations by asking you pointed questions about them. Can you please tell me where there is a jab in there? I can't repeat the content of those blog posts in a comment, which is why I posted a link instead of re-writing them in their entirety.

Comment: @Aaron That's great that your trying to "encourage" me to re-evaluate my solution. It was my understanding that this is to help out AZee, not myself. If you have a better solution to offer please post it. I honestly don't have time to completely read your blog posts right now.

Comment: @Chris Where did I say anything about your solution? Where is your solution? You've only posted comments. If you want to provide a solution, post an answer. If I told AZee to switch to Oracle or to store Unix time instead of datetime, would you not question my recommendations? We're all here to help each other, aren't we?

Comment: @Chris and if you can't bother to read my posts right now, why should anyone assume you'd have been willing to read a long-winded explanation that was posted here? The whole point of writing a blog post is precisely so that we don't have to re-write the whole manuscript every time a question comes up.

Comment: thank you so much for giving me the opportunity to learn this much from you. My apologize but still I have question with adjusting my statement to WHERE O.OrderDate >= @HOUR AND O.OrderDate < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @HOUR); because I am not getting how I can make hours dynamic or setting 1 to 0 will work? I am a newbie :)

Comment: @Aaron Thats great, I had a few minutes to help out Azee while I was waiting for something to finish up and now I'm a total a**hole because I cant read your blog post. Thanks for that.

Comment: Looks like I got it? `DECLARE @TodayDateTime smalldatetime
DECLARE @TodayDate date = @TodayDateTime
WHERE O.OrderDate >= TodayDate < TodayDateTime`

Comment: Ignoring Mr. Hyper-sensitive, I'm having a hard time understanding what this problem actually has to do with time zone. Can you show a few rows of sample data, and the query you're using that's not producing the results you expect?

Comment: Also, in the question you asked about data for a whole day, and in the comments now you 're talking about data for an hour. Can you clarify what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English to confuse you with "whole day" I think it would make more sense if would have written it as "from starting of the day to the time query runs". Any ways thanks a lot for your help and sharing that nice information on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by

```
WHERE O.OrderDate BETWEEN CAST(Convert(varchar(10), DateAdd(d, 0, getdate()), 101) + ' 12:00 AM' as datetime) AND DATEADD(hour, -5, GETUTCDATE())
```